C#, asm project returns System.AccessViolationException
I'm working on a project that simulates deuteranopia (a type of color vision deficiency) using a combination of C# and Assembly Language (ASM). The ASM code generates a DLL that processes image data, and I am experiencing a System.AccessViolationException error with the message:

An attempt was made to read or write protected memory. This often indicates that other memory is corrupt.

Project Details:
Programming Languages: C# for the main application and Assembly Language (ASM) for image processing.
Functionality: The application allows users to load an image, process it (with asm module or c# module) to simulate deuteranopia, and save the processed image.
Here’s a brief overview of the relevant code:
ASM Code (ModuleAsm.asm):
.code
DeuteranopiaAsm proc

SimulateDeuteranopiaASM:
    ; Save registers
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 32

    mov r9, rdx             ; pixelCount
    mov r8d, edi            ; threadCount (passed through edi)
    mov rdx, rcx            ; pointer to original image (originalImage)
    mov rcx, rdi            ; pointer to processed image (processedImage)

    ; Calculate the portion size for each thread
    xor rax, rax            ; Clear rax before division
    mov eax, r9d            ; Move pixelCount to eax (32-bit register for division)
    xor edx, edx            ; Clear edx (higher part of rax)
    div r8d                 ; Divide eax by r8d (threadCount in r8d, 32-bit register)
    mov r10d, eax           ; Store the result (portion size) in r10d

    ; Parallel processing
    mov eax, r10d
    mov r11, rdx            ; pointer to original image
    mov rdx, rcx            ; pointer to processed image

ProcessLoop:
    cmp r9d, 0
    je Done

    ; Load original pixel data using 8-bit registers
    movzx eax, byte ptr [r11]      ; Load red channel (R) into eax (extended to 32-bit register)
    movzx ecx, byte ptr [r11 + 1]  ; Load green channel (G) into ecx (extended to 32-bit register)
    movzx edx, byte ptr [r11 + 2]  ; Load blue channel (B) into edx (extended to 32-bit register)

    ; Simulate deuteranopia (green color blindness)
    imul eax, eax, 625         ; Transform red channel
    imul ecx, ecx, 375         ; Transform green channel
    add eax, ecx
    shr eax, 10                ; Divide by 1024
    mov [rdx + 2], al          ; Save transformed red channel to processed image

    imul ecx, ecx, 7           ; Further transform green channel
    shr ecx, 3                 ; Divide by 8
    mov [rdx + 1], cl          ; Save transformed green channel

    imul edx, edx, 8           ; Transform blue channel
    shr edx, 3                 ; Divide by 8
    mov [rdx], dl              ; Save transformed blue channel

    ; Move to the next pixel
    add r11, 3                 ; Move pointer in original image to the next pixel
    add rdx, 3                 ; Move pointer in processed image to the next pixel
    dec r9d                    ; Decrement pixel count
    jmp ProcessLoop            ; Repeat loop

Done:
    ; Restore registers
    add rsp, 32
    pop rbp
    ret
DeuteranopiaAsm endp
end


C# Code (MainWindow.xaml.cs):
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Projekt
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        // Importing the ASM function (updated with the correct path)
        [DllImport(@"C:\Users\kacpe\Desktop\home\Programing\studia\ASM-SEM-5\Projekt\x64\Debug\ModuleAsm.dll")]
        public static extern void DeuteranopiaAsm(IntPtr originalImage, IntPtr processedImage, int pixelCount, int stride, int threadCount);

        private Bitmap _originalImage;
        private Bitmap _processedImage;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            int processorThreads = Environment.ProcessorCount;
            threadSlider.Value = processorThreads;
            threadCount.Text = $"Selected threads: {processorThreads}";
        }

        private void Exit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }

        private void Window_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ButtonState == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                this.DragMove();
            }
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
            var screenWidth = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
            var screenHeight = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
            this.Left = (screenWidth - this.Width) / 2;
            this.Top = (screenHeight - this.Height) / 2;
        }

        private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            if (threadCount != null)
            {
                int threadValue = (int)threadSlider.Value;
                threadCount.Text = $"Thread count: {threadValue}";
            }
        }

        private void ChooseImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog
            {
                Filter = "Image files (*.jpg, *.png)|*.jpg;*.png",
                Title = "Choose an image"
            };

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                imagePathTextBox.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
                _originalImage = new Bitmap(openFileDialog.FileName);
                MessageBox.Show("Image loaded successfully.");
            }
        }

        private void ProcessImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_originalImage == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select an image first.");
                return;
            }

            int threadCount = (int)threadSlider.Value;

            _processedImage = new Bitmap(_originalImage.Width, _originalImage.Height);

            if (asmRadioButton.IsChecked == true)
            {
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, _originalImage.Width, _originalImage.Height);
                BitmapData originalData = _originalImage.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, _originalImage.PixelFormat);
                BitmapData processedData = _processedImage.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, _processedImage.PixelFormat);

                int pixelCount = _originalImage.Width * _originalImage.Height;
                int stride = originalData.Stride;

                IntPtr originalPtr = originalData.Scan0;
                IntPtr processedPtr = processedData.Scan0;

                // Call to the ASM function
                DeuteranopiaAsm(originalPtr, processedPtr, pixelCount, stride, threadCount);

                _originalImage.UnlockBits(originalData);
                _processedImage.UnlockBits(processedData);

                MessageBox.Show("Image processed in ASM.");
            }
            else if (cSharpRadioButton.IsChecked == true)
            {
                _processedImage = SimulateDeuteranopia(_originalImage, threadCount);
                MessageBox.Show("Image processed in C#.");
            }
        }

        private void SaveImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_processedImage == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please process the image first.");
                return;
            }

            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog
            {
                Filter = "Image files (*.jpg, *.png)|*.jpg;*.png",
                Title = "Save image"
            };

            if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                _processedImage.Save(saveFileDialog.FileName);
                MessageBox.Show("Image saved successfully.");
            }
        }

        public static Bitmap SimulateDeuteranopia(Bitmap original, int threads)
        {
            int width = original.Width;
            int height = original.Height;
            Bitmap simulatedImage = new Bitmap(width, height, original.PixelFormat);

            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, original.Width, original.Height);
            BitmapData originalData = original.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, original.PixelFormat);
            BitmapData simulatedData = simulatedImage.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, simulatedImage.PixelFormat);

            int bytesPerPixel = Image.GetPixelFormatSize(original.PixelFormat) / 8;
            int stride = originalData.Stride;
            IntPtr originalScan0 = originalData.Scan0;
            IntPtr simulatedScan0 = simulatedData.Scan0;

            byte[] originalPixels = new byte[stride * height];
            byte[] simulatedPixels = new byte[stride * height];

            Marshal.Copy(originalScan0, originalPixels, 0, originalPixels.Length);

            Parallel.For(0, threads, threadIndex =>
            {
                int partitionSize = height / threads;
                int start = threadIndex * partitionSize;
                int end = (threadIndex == threads - 1) ? height : start + partitionSize;

                for (int y = start; y < end; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                    {
                        int pixelIndex = y * stride + x * bytesPerPixel;

                        byte originalB = originalPixels[pixelIndex];
                        byte originalG = originalPixels[pixelIndex + 1];
                        byte originalR = originalPixels[pixelIndex + 2];

                        // Simulate color transformation for deuteranopia
                        int newR = (int)(originalR * 0.625 + originalG * 0.375);
                        int newG = (int)(originalG * 0.7);
                        int newB = (int)(originalB * 0.8);

                        newR = Clamp(newR, 0, 255);
                        newG = Clamp(newG, 0, 255);
                        newB = Clamp(newB, 0, 255);

                        simulatedPixels[pixelIndex] = (byte)newB;
                        simulatedPixels[pixelIndex + 1] = (byte)newG;
                        simulatedPixels[pixelIndex + 2] = (byte)newR;
                    }
                }
            });

            Marshal.Copy(simulatedPixels, 0, simulatedScan0, simulatedPixels.Length);

            original.UnlockBits(originalData);
            simulatedImage.UnlockBits(simulatedData);

            return simulatedImage;
        }

        public static int Clamp(int value, int min, int max)
        {
            if (value < min) return min;
            if (value > max) return max;
            return value;
        }
    }
}


Problem Description:
The AccessViolationException typically occurs when the code attempts to access memory that is not allowed. I suspect it could be related to how the pointers and memory are managed between the C# and ASM code. I'm locking bits of the images correctly, but I wonder if there are any memory alignment issues or if the pixel manipulation could be causing the problem.
Additional Information:

I am using .NET Framework and targeting x64 architecture.
The DLL is being loaded correctly, but crashes occur during the image processing step.
I’d appreciate any insights into common pitfalls that could lead to this exception, especially in interop scenarios between C# and ASM.

I've tried to restructure, but it leads to nothing...

I don't usually do that kind of stuff, but I'd expect to see unsafe regions? And a lot of pinned memory, probably?

"I am using .NET Framework" - I wouldn't but it should be fine, I guess. But thinking about it (just curious) why did you go with ASM over GPU-Calculation Frameworks like CUDA?

Any strong arguments for the hand written asm? There are alternatives, even c/rust with possible inline asm, sound more maintanable.

@WiktorZychla unfortunately, the use of assembler is a guideline to pass the subject

@Fildor as I told Wiktoria earlier, it wasn't my idea to use assembler, it simply needed to pass the course

Any chance to write this in Rust and just see the output assembly from the release mode?

@WiktorZychla I can try, but I think it is pointless because the assembly code is to be written by me, and as we know, the generated code in kompilation process does not resemble the code that would be written by a human.

Just for future reference: if it is homework or for a course, it should be stated in the question. Some things barely happen in real life but only in academics. You will save yourself from many "why do want xyz" comments.


You're losing the pointer to the original image

mov rdx, rcx            ; pointer to original image (originalImage)
...
xor edx, edx            ; Clear edx (higher part of rax)
div r8d                 ; Divide eax by r8d
...
mov r11, rdx            ; pointer to original image


The div r8d instruction does not "divide eax by r8d" but rather the combo EDX:EAX gets divided by R8D.
Just store the concerned pointer in R11 from the start.

; Clear edx (higher part of rax)


This shows a misconception about the x86 registers. EDX is the low 32 bits of the RDX register. RAX is a totally different register.


mov [rdx], dl              ; Save transformed blue channel


There's another severe error in this code: since you have chosen RDX as the pointer to the processed image, you can't at the same time use DL nor EDX to hold the Blue channel. DL, DH, DX, and EDX are all different parts of the same RDX register. I think you'd better pick eg. the call-clobbered R10 for an output register.
Follows two more observations:

On the input side you have Red followed by Green followed by Blue, but on the output side you reversed the order, so you have Blue followed by Green followed by Red. Is this intentional?

The transformation for the blue channel is redundant! imul edx, edx, 8 multiplies by 8, but shr edx, 3 then divides by 8 undoing the change.




mov r9, rdx             ; pixelCount
mov r8d, edi            ; threadCount (passed through edi)
mov rdx, rcx            ; pointer to original image (originalImage)
mov rcx, rdi            ; pointer to processed image (processedImage)


There's also a mismatch and an overlap in your arguments! If RDI holds a pointer to the processed image then it can't be true for EDI to hold that threadCount. EDI is not a separate register at all; EDI is the name we give to the lowest 32 bits of the RDI register.
From DeuteranopiaAsm(originalPtr, processedPtr, pixelCount, stride, threadCount);, I'd expect to find originalPtr in RCX, processedPtr in RDX, pixelCount in R8, stride in R9, and threadCount on the stack above the 32-byte shadow space.


On a more positive note, this part of my answer will focus on an actual solution.
It is important to convert your factors.
Multiplying by 0.8 (which is 80%) is the same as multiplying by 205 followed by dividing by 256. But since we can store the high byte of this product separately (from a byte-sized register), we don't need to do that actual division (not even the efficient shift 8x right). Similarly for the other factors 0.7, 0.625, and 0.375.
SimulateDeuteranopiaASM:
  ; RCX = originalImage (pointer)
  ; RDX = processedImage (pointer)
  ; R8  = pixelCount (number of pixels)

  test  r8, r8                  ; Pixelcount == 0 ?
  jz    EndLoop                 ; Yes
  mov   r10, rcx                ; Source
  mov   r11, rdx                ; Destination
PixelLoop:                      ; Load color data (B, G, R)
  movzx eax, byte ptr [r10]     ; Load blue channel
  movzx ecx, byte ptr [r10 + 1] ; Load green channel
  movzx edx, byte ptr [r10 + 2] ; Load red channel
  add   r10, 3                  ; Src++

  imul  eax, 205                ; B * 0.8    ->  B * 205 / 256
  mov   [r11], ah               ; Store blue channel

  imul  eax, ecx, 179           ; G * 0.7    ->  G * 179 / 256
  mov   [r11 + 1], ah           ; Store green channel

  imul  edx, 160                ; R * 0.625  ->  R * 160 / 256
  imul  ecx, 96                 ; G * 0.375  ->  G *  96 / 256
  add   edx, ecx                ; New Red = (R * 0.625 + G * 0.375)
  mov   [r11 + 2], dh           ; Store red channel

  add   r11, 3                  ; Dst++
  dec   r8                      ; Cnt--
  jnz   PixelLoop
EndLoop:
  ret

A quick review for your self-answer

You are loading the red channel in R8D ergo destroying the R8 pixelcount that controls your loop.

You are loading the blue channel in AL ergo destroying the RAX offset that addresses the memory.

You are calculating your fractions in a way that the channel values practically become zero. eg. times 8 followed by shift right 8x will leave about 3% of the channel!

You are using RBX without preserving it, yet the Windows 64-bit calling convention mandates that you do.



For performance, edx*160 + ecx*96 is actually possible in just 4 instructions without imul, 2x lea / add / shl by 5.  https://godbolt.org/z/aedKcfGTh .  Your current loop is 14 uops, so on Ice Lake / Zen and later can get it through the front-end in only 3 or fewer cycles per iter, and will bottleneck on imul throughput at 4 cycles per iteration.  Spending 1 extra front-end uop will remove that bottleneck so it's just a front-end bottleneck.  (Probably better to keep your answer simple, with this as a footnote. For performance you'd of course use SSE or AVX2.)

@Sep Roland
I have tried to fix my code and that is the result:
.code
DeuteranopiaAsm proc

SimulateDeuteranopiaASM:
    ; RCX = originalImage (pointer)
    ; RDX = processedImage (pointer)
    ; R8  = pixelCount (number of pixels)
    ; R9  = stride (bytes per row)

    mov r11, rcx              ; Save pointer to original image
    mov r10, rdx              ; Save pointer to processed image

    xor rbx, rbx              ; Use RBX as pixel counter

PixelLoop:
    cmp rbx, r8               ; Check if all pixels are processed
    jge EndLoop               ; If rbx >= pixelCount, exit

    mov rax, rbx              ; Copy pixel counter to rax
    shl rax, 1                ; rax = rbx * 2 (shift left by 1)
    add rax, rbx              ; rax = rax + rbx = rbx * 3

    ; Load color data (B, G, R)
    mov al, byte ptr [r11 + rax]     ; Load blue channel
    mov cl, byte ptr [r11 + rax + 1] ; Load green channel
    mov dl, byte ptr [r11 + rax + 2] ; Load red channel

    ; Simulate deuteranopia (adjust color channels)
    ; New Red channel
    movzx r8d, dl              ; Convert red channel to 32-bit
    imul r8d, 625              ; R = R * 0.625
    movzx r9d, cl              ; Convert green channel to 32-bit
    imul r9d, 375              ; G = G * 0.375
    add r8d, r9d               ; New Red = (R * 0.625 + G * 0.375)
    shr r8d, 8                 ; Divide by 256 to fit in byte range

    ; Clamp red channel
    cmp r8d, 255
    jle NoClampRed
    mov r8d, 255
NoClampRed:

    ; Transform green channel
    movzx r9d, cl              ; Reload green channel
    imul r9d, 7                ; G = G * 0.7
    shr r9d, 8                 ; Divide by 256

    ; Clamp green channel
    cmp r9d, 255
    jle NoClampGreen
    mov r9d, 255
NoClampGreen:

    ; Transform blue channel
    movzx rax, al              ; Convert blue to 32-bit
    imul rax, 8                ; B = B * 0.8
    shr rax, 8                 ; Divide by 256

    ; Clamp blue channel
    cmp rax, 255
    jle NoClampBlue
    mov rax, 255
NoClampBlue:

    ; Store processed pixel back into the image
    mov byte ptr [r10 + rax], al     ; Store blue channel
    mov byte ptr [r10 + rax + 1], cl ; Store green channel
    mov byte ptr [r10 + rax + 2], dl ; Store red channel

    inc rbx                   ; Increment pixel counter
    jmp PixelLoop             ; Repeat for next pixel

EndLoop:
    ret
DeuteranopiaAsm endp
end

The code compiles but the output image is black with strange dots in the upper left corner.
input photo
output photo

mov al, byte ptr [r11 + rax]     ; Load blue channel  - AL is the low byte of RAX, you're still  overwriting parts of pointers / indices with data.  See Assembly registers in 64-bit architecture or https://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/manual/html/manual.html#x86-registers for a reminder on the 8-bit / 16-bit / 32-bit parts of 64-bit registers.

Also, you could just movzx r8d, byte ptr [r11 + rax + 1] to directly do a zero-extending load instead of merging into the bottom of RDX first.   Or movzx load into ESI which you're not using, and do stuff like imul r8d, esi, 625 to copy-and-multiply, saving mov instructions for efficiency.

I have added a complete code to my answer, as well as a quick review for your self-answer. Please try out the code snippet.
